# How to design the connection between sensor and ADC input based on the output/input impedances?

Tags: stm32, sensor, adc, signal, impedance

I have a voltage output sensor that I'm trying to connect to my STM32 ADC. The datasheet for the sensor states:

*Assuming an effective output impedance of 25Ω, the minimum impedance of the measurement system should be 75KΩ.*

However, the STM32 datasheet states that the external input impedance (Rain) for the ADC input should not be greater than 300Ω. How do I connect the sensor to the ADC? I was originally thinking putting a 75k resistor in series to the ADC but the STM datasheet has confused me on if that's actually not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> *How do I connect the sensor to the ADC?*

Use an appropriate op-amp buffer circuit. It should have easily an input impedance into the tens of MΩ and, it's output impedance will be a few ohms. But, you do need to know the bandwidth of your signal before you start throwing any old op-amp onto a circuit board.

[How to determine what's a suitable op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/684615/how-to-determine-whats-a-suitable-opamp/684622#684622)